# Angular 2 Redux constantly re-rendering in NgFor

Tags: angular, memoization, ngrx, ngrx-store

I use NGRX in my project, and have problem with constantly re-rendering of components. 
The Store produces every time completely new object, if the store data the same, i dont want to re-render my component. I changed change detection of presentation components to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` lodash memoization (`_.memoization`), but it not works

State of store

```
export interface CardsState {
    cardsA: CardA[];
    cardsB: CardB[];
    cardsC: CardC[];
}
```

Then map Store state to structure as this

```
const entities = [{
 cards: {
  cardsB: [
   {}
  ]
 }
}];
```

And trying to prevent re-rendering of `cardsB` items every time when store changing by memoize from lodash

```
export const memoizeCardBFunc = _.memoize((cardB: CardB): CardB => {
  return _.cloneDeep(cardB);
}, (cardB: CardB) => cardB.entityType + cardB.entityId);
```

In my Smart Component i have next html

```
<div *ngFor="let entity of entities | async">
    <div *ngFor="let cardB of entity.cards.cardsB">
        <card-b [cardStateModel]="cardB"></card-b>
    </div>
</div>
```

To the my surprise it correctly works with one ngFor, but if i have two ngFor it is not works!

```
<div *ngFor="let cardB of entity.cards.cardsB">
    <card-b [cardStateModel]="cardB"></card-b>
</div>
```

I have already spended 2 days for it, and it is killing me, please, help!

I am not native English speaker, sorry for mistakes.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why or how you're using _.memoize and _.cloneDeep, but this sounds like you're doing something wrong in your reducers. If your store data stays the same, it shouldn't be returning new objects in the first place.

Comment: @matmo @Jonnysai Here is a plunker with my problem https://plnkr.co/edit/gbjdubPeZQXo7j6L3E6w?p=preview . In not works with inner ngFor. Your can remove first ngFor and second change to  `*ngFor="let cardB of entities[0].cards.cardsB; trackBy: trackByB"` and it work. I need inner ngFor (

Comment: Seems like you need a trackBy on the outer ngFor

Comment: @matmo I don`t know why, but it work with outer trackBy. Could you add this as answer, than i can mark your answer as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have:

```
<div *ngFor="let outer of outers">
    <div *ngFor="let inner of outer.inners">
       {{ inner }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then if `outer` changes at some point, the inner ngFor will re-render, which is why you see the alerts from ngOnInit. But if you add a trackBy to your outer ngFor, and it recognizes it as the same element, then you can avoid the inner list re-rendering, which is your current problem.

The inner trackBy only preserves the inner elements and prevents those from being re-created. The outer trackBy preserves the outer elements, which allows the inner elements the chance to be preserved too.

Answer (score 1):

Use trackBy in the For loop. It will keep track of State and when ever data is changed than it will trigger re render.

```
    <div *ngFor="let cardB of entity.cards.cardsB;let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <card-b [cardStateModel]="cardB"></card-b>
    </div>

trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
  }
```

read below doc you will understand more.
https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This work good when i have only one ngFor like this `*ngFor="let cardB of entities[0].cards.cardsB;` but it dont work for inner ngFor

Comment: user another trackBy for inner  loop.

Comment: i use key like in my memoization function `return item.entityId + item.entityType;}` in trackByFn